# Does anyone know this error in "d3" well?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

[image]

```
function Canvas() {
  
  // d3

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!selection) {
      setSelection(select(ref.current));
    } else {
      let x =
        defaultData.data &&
        scaleBand()
          .domain(defaultData.data!.map((d) => d.name))
          .range([0, canvas.chartWidth])
          .paddingInner(0.1);

      let y =
        defaultData.data &&
        scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, max(defaultData.data!, (d) => (axis ? d.bikeC : d.divC))!])
          .range([canvas.chartHeight, 0]);

      let color =
        defaultData.data &&
        scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, max(defaultData.data!, (d) => (axis ? d.bikeC : d.divC))!])
          .range([0.2, 0.8]);

      const xAxisBot = d3.axisBottom(x!);
      const yAxisRight = d3.axisRight(y!);

      selection
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(defaultData.data!)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        // .attr("fill", (d) => d3.interpolateGreens(color(d.divC)))
        .attr('fill', (d) =>
          axis ? d3.interpolateGreens(color!(d.bikeC!)) : d3.interpolateGreens(color!(d.divC!))
        )

        .attr('width', x!.bandwidth)
        .attr('x', (d) => x!(d.name)!)

        .attr('height', 0)
        .attr('y', canvas.chartHeight)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .delay((_, i) => i * 100)
        .ease(easeCircleOut)
        .attr('height', (d) => canvas.chartHeight - y!(axis ? d.bikeC! : d.divC!) - 10)
        .attr('y', (d) => y!(axis ? d.bikeC! : d.divC!));
```

I don't want to put in exclamation mark anymore, nor do I want to turn off null check.
so there's no other way?
This happened last time, and this made me very angry. Is there really no other way but to do nullish check for each function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
y!(axis ? d.bikeC! : d.divC!)
```

with

```
typeof y === 'function' && y(axis ? d.bikeC! : d.divC!)
```

for the sake of safety

Comment: Yeah, there's no other way.